Is there any efficient way or data structure for calculating hash of the input data?
Efficient way of calculating hash of the input data
For example, I make a storage map, of 100 keys and values. It generates a unique hash, the marker of that 100 keys and values. In another program running locally offchain, I can put the 100 keys and values, and generate the unique hash.
Need a data structure that is easier to update the storage map and the hash.
It's useful for implementing zero knowledge proof, offchain computing using risc zero.
Care needs to be taken about collision attacks, and appropriate hash functions are used.

May be markle tree which is still inefficient, or just storing new hash = hash_of(old hash + hash_of(data)) will do fine, in case of insertion or deletion, new hash = hash_of(old hash + hash_of(data, 1)) or new hash = hash_of(old hash + hash_of(data, 0)), and keeping all the deleted data in blockchain.

https://github.com/reaudito/anonymous-account-crates/blob/main/anonymous_account/host/src/accounts_hash.rs
